# Google OAuth Client Deleted, But service still trying to use it

Tags: api, authentication, oauth

I'm setting up an OAuth login flow.
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth first told me the client was deleted - which is fine - I created a new one.

Now, accounts.google returns 400 redirect_uri_mismatch (which is true if you count a trailing '?' that doesn't exist in the new client settings.
Additionally, the error page displays the OLD client project name.

It may be a propagation issue, but if anyone else has seen this behaviour, I'd like to know.

PS the target user is a GFW account.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the user was still attached to the old/deleted client, although that client had been deleted. The old and new client shared a Google API project.